# CakePHP Crud API Filtering Fields

Tags: cakephp, crud

I have written an API with the CakePHP v2.x framework. I am using the Friends of Cake Crud plugin. I need to hide sensitive data field by default for all replies, such as:

User.stripe_api_key

I have setup my component array as follows:

```
public $components = [

        'RequestHandler', 
        'Crud.Crud' => [

            'listeners' => [        
                'Api',          
                'ApiTransformation' => [

                    'changeNesting' => true, 
                    'changeKeys' => false, 
                    'changeTime' => true, 
                    'castNumbers' => true,  
                ],

                'ApiFieldFilter' => [
                    'allowNoFilter' => true,
                    'blacklistFields' => ['User.stripe_api_key']
                ],
                'ApiPagination'
            ]
        ]
];
```

This break my API though because my reply now returns 500 and:

```
"name": "Please specify which fields you would like to select",
```

According to the documentation this can be fixed with:

```
// Allow request without ?fields=
'allowNoFilter' => true,
```

Whether this value is set to true or false the reply is always 500 with the ApiFieldFilter enabled.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.